# I need to update geometry in hz_locations in Oracle CRM, Oacle R12

Tags: oracle, crm, latitude-longitude

The longitude and latitude is received through web service as characters. Kindly suggest if there is any in build package just to save the dimensions in hz_locations

Answer (score 0):

You can execute this update:

```
update hz_locations set geometry = sdo_geometry(2001,8307,SDO_POINT_TYPE (v_longitude_x,v_latitude_y,NULL), NULL, NULL) where location_id = p_location_id;
```